# How to describe Proc in RubyDoc?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a gem that adds some special capabilities to user classes with ability to override it by supplying lambdas/procs:

```
class EndUserClass
  include SpecificDSL

  set_godzilla_handler(
    lambda do |godzilla, megatron, &scream_generator|
      godzilla.attac
      megatron.protec
      scream_generator.call('AAAAAAAAAA')
    end
  )
end
```

I need to clearly document what parameters are fed in to user-supplied Proc and what value library expects Proc to return. How can i do that via RubyDoc?

Comment: Is `godzilla_handler` here a local variable or a method call to a mutator `godzilla_handler=`?

Comment: @tadman a mutator, will clarify in a second

Comment: If this is an API you control it might be worth re-thinking how you define these handlers. If it's beyond your control then it depends on your documentation system. Rdoc, RI and Yard all have different ideas.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason your method should need to take a lamba/proc, and not a block as well. In yard there is a [yield](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#yield) label you can use, and the functionality here seems to be the same as `yield`.

Comment: @maxpleaner missed that one, thank you